# LU Factorization with Pivoting in Matlab without abs function

Tags: matlab

Any help would be appreciated, the output does not make sense and I am unsure what is wrong.I am trying to perform the function listed in the title.

```
function [L,U,P]=lufactor(A);

A= [2 1 1 0;
4 3 3 1;
8 7 9 5;
6 7 9 8];

[Row1,~] = size(A); 
L=eye(Row1); 
P=eye(Row1); 
U=A;

for i=1:Row1
nrow(i)=i;
end
nrow=nrow';

for k=1:Row1-1;
max=0;
for j = k:Row1 %Go through vector one value at a time
  if abs(nrow(j))>max; %Determine if value in vector is greater than the          current value
      max=abs(nrow(j));
  if max ~= k %perform row exchange
      U([max,j],:) =  U([j,max], :);   % interchange rows m and j in U
      P([max,j],:) =  P([j,max], :);   % interchange rows m and j in P
  if j >= 2    
      L([max,j],1:j-1) =  L([j,max], 1:j-1);   % interchange rows m and j in columns 1:j-1 of L
  end
  end
  end
 for i = j+1:Row1      
      L(i, j) = U(i, j) / U(j, j);
      U(i, :) =  U(i, :) - L(i, j)*U(j, :);
     end
    end
    end
```

[L,U,P]

Current Output, with results organized [L,U,P]:

```
 1     0     0     0     2     1     1     0     1     0     0     0
 2     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     1     0     0
 4     0     1     0     0     0     2     2     0     0     1     0
 3     0     0     1     0     0     0     2     0     0     0     1
```

Expected Output:

L=

```
1.0000         0         0         0
0.7500    1.0000         0         0
0.5000   -0.2857    1.0000         0
0.2500   -0.4286    0.3333    1.0000
```

U =

```
8.0000    7.0000    9.0000    5.0000
     0    1.7500    2.2500    4.2500
     0         0   -0.8571   -0.2857
     0         0         0    0.6667
```

P =

```
 0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     1
 0     1     0     0
 1     0     0     0
```

Comment: You should post an example of the output you are receiving, as well as the output you are expecting.

Comment: Hi Dianna, you will want to edit your question with the current and expected output instead of adding it to the comments.  This will allow reviewers of your question to see the example right away without having to search the comments for it.  Welcome to Stack Overflow, I hope someone can help you with your problem.